# Mercurial: Check which files will be adding before adding

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository

I want to make sure my regexp in .htignore are working correctly. Before adding files to the repository, I would like to see which files `hg add` command would add. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"hg status" will as the name implies show you the status of the files.

From "hg help status"

```
The codes used to show the status of files are:
M = modified
A = added
R = removed
C = clean
! = missing (deleted by non-hg command, but still tracked)
? = not tracked
I = ignored
  = origin of the previous file listed as A (added)
```

You can also run "hg add -n" which is dry run and will only print the output but not do any thing to the repository.

Comment: If you're using TortoiseHg, then `hgtk st` aka `hgtk status` is useful as it puts a friendly GUI on top of the basic `hg status`.

Comment: @NathanE: Possibly worth mentioning that with the latest versions of TortoiseHg, the command has changed from `hgtk` to `thg`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with NA's answer, but it should also be noted that you can `hg add` anything, even files that are already being ignored by the .hgignore filter. In other words, if your .hgignore contains this:

`glob:*.abc`

you can still explicitly add files of type *.abc.

Comment: Hmm... so if I do hg add, the files that are supposed to be ignore will be added to? Then where is the ignore really happening?

Comment: The ignore happens during the `hg add` command. I think dls means that you could add an ignored file by stating it explicitly on the command line: `hg add myfile.abc`.